# facebook dialog feed custom picture from your app instead of an url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, facebook

Is it possible to encode a picture from our iPhone to use with facebook dialog feed instead of passing an URL.. !

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Blablabla", @"name",
                               @"Blablabla", @"caption",
                               @"Blablabla", @"description",
                               @"http://google.com", @"link",
                               @"HTTP:CAN IT BE AN ENCODED PICTURE??", @"picture",
                               actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                               nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

There's a reference link for params:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck at the same problem and was quite shocked that there's no support for uploading images. My solution was to upload the picture to my remote web server and use the link that I've got from server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uploading to Amazon s3 then using that url to post to the feed.